# Nested inline-blocks won't wrap properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Oriol answered my question pretty perfectly:**
Instead of using inline-block on the two containers, I should float the first container, and leave the second without any particular styling. At the same time I should use overflow:hidden on the main container and the second container to avoid awkward wrapping outside the box.

---

### Original Question

I am working on a pretty simple profile page in a responsive layout. The profile itself is contained in a DIV which is fixed to the bottom of the screen.

See a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ner8j6vz/

The profile consists of two container DIVs, nested inside a main container:

- Profile picture and UL with information (fixed width)
- Menu with DIVs (which should wrap as the container shrinks or expands)

The containers are shown as inline-block, with white-space:nowrap to prevent them from wrapping (obvious, I suppose). So the containers line up nicely, but now I have another problem - the second container doesn't follow the main container's width, so the menu DIVs won't wrap like I want them to.

I figured this should have been quite simple, but apparently it's not. Of course there is a great chance I have simply missed something crucial, and am now blind to it from searching for other problems.

I don't want to clutter the question by trying to explain what I've tried before, but I have experimented with variations of floating and inline-block, and read a dozen articles on how float and inline-block works and how to try and deal with their quirks. I am assuming my problem is related to how the first container has static width, while the second has fluid width, but I have no idea how.

Code:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="subcontainer1">
    </div>
    <div id="subcontainer2">
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
        <div class="menuelement"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#maincontainer
{
    height:150px;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#subcontainer1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid rgb(240,90,40);
}
#subcontainer2
{
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.menuelement
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(240,90,40);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using floats. This way `#subcontainer2` will still be a block element, and adjust its width to avoid overflowing `#maincontainer`.

```css
#maincontainer {
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#subcontainer1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%; /* consider `calc(100% - 3px)`,
                   or `box-sizing: border-box`  */
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid rgb(240, 90, 40);
}
#maincontainer, #subcontainer2 {
  overflow: hidden; /* clear float */
}
.menuelement {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 90, 40);
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer">
  <div id="subcontainer1"></div>
  <div id="subcontainer2">
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
    <div class="menuelement"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried this earlier, but with float on both the containers.
Silly question with a simple solution - sorry for making you spend time on something like this. I really appreciate it though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not positive but is this the effect you're looking for? Using floats may be the way to go. https://jsfiddle.net/ner8j6vz/4/

```
#maincontainer {
overflow:hidden;
width:80%;
height:158px;
}
#subcontainer1 {
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
width:100px;
height:154px;
border:2px solid rgb(240, 90, 40);
}
#subcontainer2 {
height:100%;
vertical-align:top;
}
.menuelement {
display:inline-block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:rgb(240, 90, 40);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Same solution as Oriol, but with some extra tricks to make my demo look prettier I see. I'd upvote you if I had enough reputation!

Comment: No worries, once you incorporate it into your design you can tweak it around and make it suit your layout.